# storing domain class in flow scope

Tags: grails, spring-webflow

In a Grails web flow I store a `List` of the following objects in flow scope.

```
class ParsedBrochure implements Serializable {

    Brochure brochure
    transient MessageSource messageSource

    boolean hasVirtualOrderError = false
    boolean hasVirtualSubOrderError = false
    boolean hasStoreGroupsError = false
    boolean hasPdfError = false

    List<String> messages = []
}
```

`Brochure` is a `Serializable` domain class that is validated before it is stored into flow scope. If this validation produces errors such that:

```
parsedBrochure.brochure.hasErrors() == true
```

When I retrieve (deserialise) the object from flow scope in the GSP, these errors have disappeared. So somehow, in between storing the object into flow scope in the web flow state and retrieving it from flow scope in the GSP, the errors have vanished.

I've checked that everything is `Serializable` including

- `Brochure` itself
- `Brochure.errors`
- Each object stored in `Brochure.errors.errors`

At this point I'm all out of ideas...

Comment: One thing to note is that hasErrors only reports if errors were found during the last validation. If a subsequent validation is performed before hasErrors is called, it may clear out the errors if none were found the second time. Not saying this is your case, just an FYI - as it happened to me and it took me a while to discover.

Comment: I had the same problems severals weeks ago, I gave up and ended with the following work around: (re)calling `validate()` from gsp like this: `<g:set var="hasError" value="${myInstance?.validate()}" />` ...

Comment: @aiolos I tried this, but I get an error telling me there's no Hibernate Session bound to the GSP thread (the validation needs to access the database).